# Implicit Differentiation: Quadrifolium

Tags: implicit-differentiation

The Question is:

Let $(x^2+y^2)^3=(x^2-y^2)^2$ be a curve. Find the points on the curve where the normal line is parallel to y=0.

I have $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{-x(3x^4+6x^2y^2+3y^4-1)}{y(3x^4+6x^2y^2+3y^4+1)}$= a/0

as the slope of the normal line equals $\dfrac{-1}{(dy/dx)} $

How can I find the points on the curve?

Comment: $y=0$ is vertical. Hence, you are looking for points where $\frac{dy}{dx}=\infty$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Do I substitute x or y to satisfy that equation?

Comment: Well, $x\neq0,\;y=0$ is a solution, and inside the parenthesis, replace $u=x^2,v=y^2$, and solve as if its a quadratic.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @amd There is more than one solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrifolium

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Oops. Forgot to square the right side. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Are you sure about the differentiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your implicit differentiation went wrong.  Here it goes:
$$3(x^2+y^2)^2(2x+2yy')=2(x^2-y^2)(2x-2yy').$$
For our purpose it's better to take the derivative in respect to $y$, since we want $x'=0$, so
$$3(x^2+y^2)^2(2xx'+2y)=2(x^2-y^2)(2xx'-2y).$$
Now if $x'=0$ we get
$$3(x^2+y^2)^22y=2(x^2-y^2)(-2y).$$
We notice that $y=0$ is a solution, from which we get $x\in\{0,1,-1\}$.

If $y\neq0$, we have
$$3(x^2+y^2)^2=-2(x^2-y^2).\qquad\qquad(*)$$
Squaring gives 
$$9(x^2+y^2)^4=4(x^2-y^2)^2.$$
Since $(x^2-y^2)^2=(x^2+y^2)^3$, we achieve
$$x^2+y^2=4/9,$$
plugged in $(*)$ gives
$$x^2-y^2=-8/27.$$
Adding the last two equations gives
$$2x^2=\frac{4}{27}\iff x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2}{27}}=\pm\frac{\sqrt2}{3\sqrt3}.$$
 Now expand this fraction by $\sqrt3$ to get
$$x=\pm\frac{\sqrt2\sqrt3}{3\sqrt3\sqrt3}=\pm\frac{\sqrt6}{9}.$$

Similarly, by subtracting both equations we get $y=\pm\sqrt{30}/9$.

Hence we have four more solutions, namely
$$\frac19(\pm\sqrt6,\pm\sqrt{30}).$$

[image]

Comment: is the $x= \pm \frac {\sqrt6} {9}$ a tangent line?

Comment: Exactly, the red and green line.

Comment: How did you get the points from the last two equations?

Comment: Adding the equations gives $2x^2$, subtracting them gives $2y^2$.

Comment: woud you mind elaborating on that?

Comment: @PeterFerri See my edit, please.